# PERL: DBI connect('','system',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate while using dbi personal package

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I'm trying to create an application class with uses DBD::Oracle. I have an issue with ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables.

When I set those variables with in a BEGIN enclosure, it works fine, see example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use DBI;

# Debug
use Data::Dumper;

package DBIAgent;

BEGIN
{
    $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}="/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1";
    $ENV{ORACLE_SID}="DB01";
}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _username => shift,
        _password => shift,
        _database => shift,
        _logger => shift
    };

    $self->{_oracleConnected} = 0;

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;    
}

sub TO_JSON {
  return { %{ shift() } };
}

sub connect {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    foreach (sort keys %ENV) { 
        $self->{_logger}->log ("INFORMATION - $_  =  $ENV{$_}");
    }

    $self->{_logger}->log ("INFORMATION - Username " . $self->{_username});
    $self->{_logger}->log ("INFORMATION - Password " . $self->{_password});

    eval {
        $self->{_oracleConnexion} = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:", $self->{_username}, $self->{_password}, {ora_verbose=>6}) or die ("ERROR - Unable to connect to database " . $self->{_database} . " - " . $! . " SQL ERROR: " . $DBI::errstr);
    };

    if ($@) {
        $self->{_oracleConnected} = 0;
        $self->{_logger}->log ($@);
    } else {
        $self->{_oracleConnected} = 1;
        $self->{_logger}->log ("INFORMATION - Connected to database " . $self->{_database});
    }

    return $self->{_oracleConnected};
}

sub getSqlResult {
    my ( $self, $sqlName, $sqlText ) = @_;
    my $resultSet;

    eval {
        $resultSet = $self->{_oracleConnexion}->selectall_arrayref($sqlText) or die ("ERROR - Execution for sql " . $sqlName . " on database " . $self->{_database} . " failed - SQL ERROR: " . $DBI::errstr);
    };

    if ($@) {
        $self->{_logger}->log ($@);
        return "";
    } else {
        return $resultSet;
    }
}

sub close {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    $self->{_oracleConnexion}->disconnect();
    $self->{_oracleConnected} = 0;
    $self->{_logger}->log ("INFORMATION - Disconnected from database " . $self->{_connexionInfo}->{database});
}

# Getters / Setters

sub getConnected {
    my( $self ) = @_;
    return $self->{_oracleConnected};
}

1;
```

When I remove the BEGIN section, I get the following error:
DBI connect('','system',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate

My Oracle architecture may be with more than one ORACLE_HOME, so that's why I would like to make it as a variable parameter.

I tried to set it before creating the DBIAgent object but I get the same error. I own that I have to set those variables before the use DBI; command is called.

Is there a way to parameter the BEGIN section, or is there another way to do that ?

Thanks for your help.
Ragards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using 2 environment variables here with two *very* different purposes.

---

If you want to connect to different Oracle Instances, dump/override the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable and use the connection string in `DBD::Oracle->connect` to pass the SID.
One line from the docs shows this example:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=foobar;sid=DB;port=1521', 'scott/tiger', '');
```

More details @ https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#connect

---

`ORACLE_HOME` on the other hand points to the location of the Oracle Client software installed on your machine and tells the XS components of `DBD::Oracle` where to find the necessary libraries with which to link.  I can't really think of a good reason you'd want to make this variable in a production environment. The fact that a fresh installation of `DBD::Oracle` requires the compilation of those XS components against those same client libraries could easily complicate your attempts. Odds are you'll want to use the most recent version on the machine.  `ORACLE_HOME` is almost always set by login script, /etc/init.d script or by specific `cron` jobs.

One exception might be in a testing environment, but in that case you'll probably be well equipped to vary an environment variable to test each candidate client.

Comment: I would like to connect BEQ by setting ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID, so without using le listener with could be down. ORACLE_HOME can be variable as in RAC environnments (Grid Infrastructure, and Database home). I have used a workaround which is to package an instant client with my perl bin and use it in my package.

Answer (score 1):

The `%ENV` hash is a way to access your shell's environment variables. So you can fix the problem by setting the environment variables outside of your program, before you call it.

```
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
$ export ORACLE_SID=DB01
$ ./name_of_your_program
```

Don't forget to remove the whole `BEGIN` block as well.

Comment: As I said, I know that it works but I have multiple database home and I would like to have one unique package in which I can parameter ORACLE_HOME on object creation for example.